# Not able to use a list in a if-statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying to make a loop that allowed me to retrieve tokenized data values in a list, check if there's stop words inside the tokenized cell value and append it to a new list.

```
# Importing the packages to be used

import xlrd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Declaration of file path of the data and opening of workbook and worksheet

file_path = "C:/Users/L31101/Documents/Data/Copy_1.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("ConsolidateModuleQnComment")

# Grabs the numbers of rows and columns of the worksheet

rowcount = worksheet.nrows
columncount = worksheet.ncols

# Prints the number of row and columns

print("\nRow count: %d" % rowcount)
print("Column count: %d" % columncount)

# Grabbing the cell values and placing them inside an array named data_value

data_value = []

for rowindex in range(2, rowcount):
    # print("\nCurrent row number: %d" % rowindex)
    # print(worksheet.cell_value(rowindex, 6))
    data_value.append(worksheet.cell_value(rowindex, 6))

# Grabbing the values inside data_value cell and tokenizes them, and then adds them into the data_tokenized array

data_tokenized = []

for valueindex in range(0, len(data_value)):
    data_tokenized.append(word_tokenize(data_value[valueindex]))

# Grabbing the tokenized values from the data_tokenized array and removing the stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

data_stopword_removed = []

for tokenizedindex in range(0, len(data_tokenized)):
    if data_tokenized[tokenizedindex] not in stop_words:
        data_stopword_removed.append(data_tokenized[tokenizedindex])

print("\nNumber of records: %d" % len(data_stopword_removed))
```

It gives the following error message

```
C:\Users\L31101\PycharmProjects\Year3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/L31101/PycharmProjects/Year3/SentimentAnalysis.py

Row count: 5792
Column count: 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L31101/PycharmProjects/Year3/SentimentAnalysis.py", line 47, in <module>
    if test_variable not in stop_words:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas how I may fix this?

Comment: Why `test_variable = data_tokenized[1]`?  `1` will always be the same element.

Comment: I tried to test it with just one variable and a specific one because when I put an array in, it didn't work. I'll post the other code with the first thing I tired, but both methods didn't work

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: You are not showing the code that causes the error. The error is on the line that said: `if test_variable not in stop_words:` and I don't see that line in your code. Any way, the error said: your `test_variable`, which is a list, is not allowed in this test. You will have a better luck with a tuple or other hashable types such as `str`, `int`, `bool`, `tuple` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out `test_variable` on the line before the error. It’ll be a list. Lists can’t be put in sets because lists are mutable and don’t have a `__hash__` method which is required. If lists can’t be put in a set, you can’t search a set for a list. Hence the error `unhashable type`.

Without knowing what you’re exactly trying to test here, I can’t say what your fix is going to be. But whatever it is, you’re going to need to test against something other than a `list`.

Comment: Even when I've inserted the statement test_variable before the if statement, it still returns the same error that it's a list.

Comment: Sorry yes. That's just to help with debugging and show that it's a list. I think there's a problem with your logic here. What are you trying to test? That one particular element is not in the set? That none of the elements in the list are in the set? That some elements in the list are not in the set?

Comment: What I'm trying to test is if I grab just a specific value from an array, am I able to remove its stopwords and append it to a new list where all the tokenized values don't have stopwords because doing it with the whole loop doesn't work

Comment: What type is the "specific value"?

Comment: The value is a tokenized sentence. E.G. Hi this is a sentence. Welcome to Stack Overflow. ["Hi", "this", "is", "a", "sentence", ".", "Welcome", "to", "Stack", "Overflow"]

Comment: So how about something like: `cleaned = [t for t in data_tokenized[tokenizedindex] if t not in stop_words]` to produce a list of tokens not in the `stop_words` set?

Comment: data_stopword_removed = [t for t in data_tokenized[valueindex] if t not in stop_words] only returned 28 records when there's 5792 rows in the excel.